# Why Object is required to be created in base constructor in ES6 JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

JavaScript ES6 support `class` and `constructor` like below. But it specifies that the new `Object` is created in base constructor instead of entering the constructor of derived class. Why is this requirement necessary? Could it create when begins constructor in `Derived` class and then pass to `Base` class to do initialization?

```
class Base {
  constructor(){
    // implicit call to Object.create(new.target.prototype)
  }
}
class Derived extends Base {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this); // complain this is not defined
    super();
    console.log(this); // it is fine to access this here
  }
}
```

Comment: The reasoning is also discussed [here.](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/super-on-class-that-extends)

Comment: The TLDR is that `implicit call to Object.create(new.target.prototype)` is only the implicit behavior _some_ of the time. The call to `super()` is what decides what `this` should be, and if you extend an `Array` for instance, it doesn't do your implicit behavior, it does something else. If `this` existed earlier, there would be no way to extend types like `Array`.